# C# - Help with Customised DatagridView Cell Options

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to customise a DataGridView cell to include a combobox and 
a text field. So far myCell class derives from DataGridViewTextBoxCell 
class. 
My class has a Combobox as a private member but I am not sure how I 
can render it. I am overriding the Pain method but I have no idea how 
to draw the combobox. I set its location to be at the origin of the 
cell and its size to be equal to cellBounds size. I know that if I was 
creating a combobox on a form I would have to add it to my forms 
controls list for example so it would get drawn but in this case I 
really dont know how to do it.

Note: I am not using any sort of sql db.

Ideally I would have a combobox displayed on the top half of my cell 
and a text box on the bottom half of my cell where users could change 
the text at runtime.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: btw. I love the Pain() method :)

Answer (score 3):

I would try to derive from IDataGridViewEditingControl and a custom UserControl which has exacty your requirements (TextBox and ComboBox).
But check, if a ComboBox on its own is not already enough. Depending on the DropDownStyle your user can already change the content of the ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I have created a NewColumn class, a NewCell class (derived from DataGridViewTextBoxCell) and a userControl that contains a combobox and a text box. Why did you mention to derive the newCell from IDataGridViewEditingControl? I still cant see the user control being drawn.

Comment: Well, at least in editmode you should see the custom usercontrol. The cell itself will still have to paint (pretend) that there is a combobox + a textbox. Maybe the [mono implementation](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA007D20790ED5F373E98CDAB06E10F7788C648E3.aspx) helps you?

Comment: I created an EditingControl that derives from myUserControl and IDataGridViewEditingControl and added the override functions as shown on the example you sent. I can see my control now (event though I have to click on the cell or type something for it to show up) :)
On resize it is not repainting it properly... A good starting point anyway, thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that InitializeEditingControl() is the one responsible for displaying my user control on the cell but it is only called once I click on the cell. Calling it just after I add a row breaks as it says the state of the cell is not right. Any ideas how I can solve this?
Regarding resizing, calling editControl.Invalidate() doesnt redraw my user control... there must be something else that needs to be done, no?